# server initialize error... have to use "ps aux | grep rails" everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I run the server using

```
rails s
```

I get this message:

```
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-08-12 19:57:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-08-12 19:57:32] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [i686-linux]
[2012-08-12 19:57:32] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
Exiting
/home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in        `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-    p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `new'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `block in create_listeners'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `each'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `create_listeners'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:82:in `listen'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:70:in `initialize'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-    1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `new'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `run'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /home/abhishek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

And then I have to use

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

and

```
kill -9 <pid> 

rails s
```

My question is:

Is there a way so that I dont have to do this and i can easily run the server using

```
rails s
```

every time..

even though.. the command

```
rails s -p 4000
```

works..

I am just curious if there is any way i can use the same port every time... so that I do not have to start with a different port every time I start the server as this makes me have to re-enter the specific controller and action name again and again...

Comment: you could `killall -9 rails` but the main issue here is that apparently rails is already running without you knowing it - is it started at system start?  If so, why do you want to restart it?  And wouldn't in that case `/etc/init.d/rails restart` be an option (the exact name of the script in init.d may be different, check init.d)

Comment: how do you close the server , any error message while exit?

Comment: @fvu when I ran the `killall -9 rails` it gave this output `rails: no process found`

Comment: @PriteshJ when I am done I just close the terminal.. I do not get any error messages... Sorry if I misunderstood ur question... I am new at rails..

Comment: you understood correctly. is this happening frequently?

Comment: @PriteshJ yes every time I run this `rails s` or now with every time that I run `rails s -p 4000` so now I have to use `rails s -p x` and I  increment x with 1 every time I run the server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you close the terminal I suggest you to close the server first using `ctrl+c` then close the terminal

this releases the port the server was using.

now when you start a server again you can use the same port, you do not need to use new one.

If **sometimes** it is not released properly kill the server and use it.

kill server using `killall -9 rails`

This way you should be able to use `rails s` everytime to start the server.

@Andrei's answer is useful and correct but I feel it should be used when you need to start multiple servers at a single time , you want to run the server to run explicitly on another port.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... This is exactly what I needed... What I was doing wrong all along was that instead of using `Ctrl c` I was using `Ctrl z` and I started using `Ctrl z` only for one stupid reason that z is closer to Ctrl key than c.. And then I guess I forgot that I could have used `Ctrl c` and just started using 'z' instead... Thank you..

Comment: ctrl+z just stops the process like in paused state which caused the issue , glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

When you run 'rails s', by default it will always start a server on port 3000. So if you already have one server running its probably running on port 3000. You could start a second (third, fourth etc) server by specifying a different port by passing '-p' option.

```
rails s -p 4000
```

Comment: This works and I tried different port numbers and all of them worked.. thank you..